# how to give multiple condition for "on" in dotnet core join

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

how to give multiple condition for "on" in dotnet core join like-

```
from x in this.context.RegulatoryUpdates
join m in this.context.RegulatoryUpdateClient on **x.Id equals m.RegulatoryupdateId  and  id = 25** into m
from z in m.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create anonymous objects:

```
from x in this.context.RegulatoryUpdates
join m in this.context.RegulatoryUpdateClient on new { x.Id, id } equals new { Id = m.RegulatoryupdateId, id = 25 } into m
from z in m.DefaultIfEmpty()
```